# Algorithm for optimally matching certain sized volunteer groups with volunteer sites asking for specific numbers of volunteers?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have groups of volunteers of various sizes (from 5 people to 250 people) that need to be paired with volunteer sites requesting various numbers of volunteers (from 3 people to 400 people). I need to pair volunteer groups with volunteer sites, splitting volunteer groups when needed and pairing multiple volunteer groups with a single volunteer site when necessary. However, I would like to minimize any splitting. Is there an algorithm to pair these most optimally? Does this fall under a known type of computer science problem that has Wikipedia pages which would help? Any suggestions are appreciated​!

Comment: What you describe sounds a bit like a [flow network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) but the minimizing of splits does not really fit in. I think although the algorithms about weighted max/min bipartite matching might give you some ideas on how to develop an algorithm for your problem. I'd personally try to model the problem using [constraint programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming).

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be interpreted as a variant of the **transportation problem**. Consider the bipartite graph with source nodes (volunteer groups, denoted by `i`) and destination nodes (volunteer sites, denoted by `j`). Let's assume the total number of volunteers is equal or larger than total demand by the sites. Then the objective is to minimize the number of used links from `i → j`.

This problem can be formulated as a **mixed integer programming model** and solved with readily available MIP solvers. The model can look like:

[image]

The items *x<sup>up</sup><sub>i,j</sub>* indicate the upperbounds on *x<sub>i,j</sub>*.

Let's generate some random data:

```
----     18 PARAMETER size  volunteers in group

group1   47,    group2  212,    group3  140,    group4   79,    group5   76,    group6   60,    group7   91
group8  215,    group9   21,    group10 128,    group11 250,    group12 147


----     18 PARAMETER request  needed by site

site1 397,    site2 306,    site3  55,    site4 257,    site5  66


----     18 PARAMETER numvolunteer         =         1466  total volunteers
            PARAMETER numrequest           =         1081  total requests
```

When feeding this data into our model we get the following results:

```
----     44 VARIABLE y.L  link used

              site1       site2       site3       site4       site5

group2                        1
group3                                                1
group4                                                            1
group5                                    1
group8                        1
group10                                               1
group11           1
group12           1


----     44 VARIABLE x.L  flow

              site1       site2       site3       site4       site5

group2                       91
group3                                              140
group4                                                           66
group5                                   55
group8                      215
group10                                             117
group11         250
group12         147
```

Answer (score 0):

I will need more specifics on what you are trying to optimize, but here is a solution that will get it done.

Things you may want to consider:

1. Do you want to allocate the maximum number of people possible or the maximum number of groups? My algorithm is made to maximize the number of matched groups.
2. Do you still want to match incomplete groups? My algorithm might create 1 volunteer match that is incomplete, but I thought that it might be worthwhile anyway, and then you can just fill it later.

First, create two dictionaries, volunteerGroups (with a key for the group number or name, and the number needed as the value) and a volunteersNeeded (with a key for the group number or name and the number needed as the value). Use collections to sort the dictionaries.

```
import collections
volunteerGroups = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(volunteerGroups.items()))
volunteersNeeded = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(volunteersNeeded.items()))
```

Create a dictionary for the matchings:

```
volunteerMatches = {}
```

Next, start by finding a fit for the smallest amounts of volunteers needed.

```
for v in volunteersNeeded.keys():

    matches = False

    for v2 in volunteerGroup.keys():

        if volunteerGroup[v2]>=volunteersNeeded[v]:

            volunteerMatches[v] = v2 #dictionary entry matching group to assignment

            #remove matched groups
            del volunteerGroup[v2]
            del volunteerGroup[v]

#Now match any groups that couldn't fit 1 to 1
for v in volunteersNeeded.keys():

    matched = false
    vg = volunteerGroups.keys()
    volunteerMatches[v] = []

    while matched == false and len(vg)>0:

        for v2 in volunteerGroups.keys():

            if volunteersNeeded[v]>0:
                volunteersNeeded[v] = volunteersNeeded[v]-volunteerGroups[v2]
                volunteerMatches[v].append(volunteerGroups[v2])
                del volunteerGroups[v2] #delete the group that was added to this project
            #once you finish a group, you can move on
            if volunteersNeeded[v]<=0:
                matched = true
                break

#print out all the matches
for match in volunteerMatches.keys():
    print(volunteerMatches[match])
```